# Inheritance and knockoutjs

Tags: inheritance, knockout.js, coffeescript

```
class ViewModel
  constructor: ->
    $.ajax({url: '#.json', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json'})
    .done @buildModel

  buildModel: (data) =>
    @model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data)
    @model.update = =>
      delete @model.update
      jsonForm = ko.mapping.toJSON(@model)
      $.ajax({url: '#.json', data: jsonForm, type: 'PUT', contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: 'json'})
      .done @buildModel

    ko.applyBindings(@model)

###################################################################

class FormViewModel extends ViewModel
  buildModel: =>
    super()
```

If I call this:

```
$(document).bind 'pageinit', =>
  @form = new ViewModel
```

everything is fine. If I try to inherit

```
$(document).bind 'pageinit', =>
  @form = new FormViewModel
```

getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: update is not defined;
Bindings value: click: update
```

Why ko.applyBindings is not happy with this inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `super` instead of `super()` in `FormViewModel`'s `buildModel` function.

- `super()` means: call the parent method of the same name, without any arguments.
- `super` means: call the parent method of the same name, with whatever arguments I received.

So the subclass was always calling the parent `buildModel` function with data = `undefined`.

Also note that I don't think you should need to call `ko.applyBindings` in the `buildModel` function. The call should only need to happen once for the entire view model.